# Multi threading which allows mutiple threads with different id's to enter the critical section

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a scenario where I have a `method(int id)` which has a critical section inside it. When multiple threads call this method with different id's these multiple threads can be given access to critical section, but when a new thread with an `id` (method param) "x" try to enter the critical section which is already having a thread with same id the other thread shouldn't be able to enter.

Let know if any more info is needed.

Comment: Yes, code would be helpful with the written scenario.

Comment: [Intrinsic Locks and Synchronization](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/locksync.html)

Comment: @AndyTurner wouldn't that still block every thread once the first one occupies the lock object?

Comment: if you google "java get lock by id" you will see many answers from stackoverlfow

Comment: @AndyTurner what could be the difference b/w integer and long in this scenario

Comment: @andy Turner
worked fine for some of the scenarios where i used int,though havent tried all the scenarios,would be good if the sol'n specified would be generic one..Thnx
public void idMethod(int id,Thread t){
  synchronized (Integer.valueOf(id)){
   System.out.println("thread name is"+t.getName());
   try {
    Thread.sleep(3000);
   } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
   }
   System.out.println("thread value is"+id);
   System.out.println("critical section");
  }
  }

Comment: @k.explorer please [edit] your question to add code; it is unreadable in comments.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a `ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, Object>`, private to the class containing the critical section, and hold a monitor object per ID:

```
private final ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, Object> locks = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
```

then

```
synchronized (locks.computeIfAbsent(id, id -> new Object())) {
  // Critical section.
}
```

This atomically inserts an object into the map when a new ID is encountered, and returns it; the block is then synchronized on the arbitrary object.

When the same ID is encountered, the previously-created object is returned; this prevents two threads with the same ID being in the block at the same time.

Comment: When are entries ever dropped from the map? Potentially that could become a quite large quantity of data.

Comment: Never, unless you do something to clean them up explicitly.

Comment: Yeah yeah, but my question really is: what can we come up with to clean up the map? Removing entries is tricky, would require an extra synchronized block i think

Comment: @AdriaanKoster hmm, I think I came up with a neat solution for this previously. I will have a dig.

Comment: Maybe each thread can replace the monitor with a new one on entry and remove it just before exiting the synchronized block? No, that won't work if multiple threads are blocking on the same monitor.

Comment: Doesnt work like that. Assume 2 threads (T1,T2) waiting on the first `synchronized` with instance (O1) on the same lock (a third (T3) is in the critical region). T3 exits the method, removes the lock O1. T2 gets into the first synchronized block and creates lock O2 and processes. T4 arrives and waits on O2. Current state: T3 waits on O1, T2 holds O1 and O2, T4 waits on O2. T2 exits the methods. T3 and T4 can enter the first synchronized block, and both create a new lock O3/O4 and both enter the critical region.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing a simple solution would be to store the IDs in a list, and check if the thread's ID is inside the list already. Once the threads finish the critical code, remove their IDs from the list.

Usually for preventing access to critical sections you would use synchronization blocks, but since you need to block access only to "duplicate" threads, I don't think it can be done that way.

Comment: You should mention that a global lock is required for the modification of that list. Waiting for the id to be released is also not an easy task.

Comment: @Memfisto this is a simple, but incorrect solution. Synchronization is needed to avoid multiple threads processing the same ID.

Comment: How sound could this approach be.its as @memfisto specified but handled differently

set inputs<Integer> =new HashSet();
void doSmoething(){
synchronize(this){
while(inputs.contains(i)){
wait();}
inputs.add(i);
}
//critical section code
synchronize(this){
inputs.remove(i);
notofyAll();
}
}

Comment: @AdriaanKoster I completely overlooked that. Can you have synchronization only for processing the same IDs? Let's say a small block that only sets a boolean for that thread that indicates if it can enter a critical block of code that is outside of the sync block? That way it shouldn't clog the threads trying to access it.

Answer (score 1):

You could store the monitors/locks into a ConcurrentHashMap and retrieve the appropriate lock by the id. If you want to be able to prune the Map of unnecessary ids from the map, you can use WeakReferences. It is a bit more tricky to handle but doable.

A weakreference makes sure that if the lock object is still referenced by at least one other thread, all threads use that instance. If none uses it `WeakReference.get()` will return null.

Something like that:

```
private static final ConcurrentMap<Integer, WeakReference<Object>> MONITORS = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

public void method(int id) {
    Object lock = getLock(id);
    synchronized (lock) {

    }
}

private Object getLock(int id) {
    Object newLock = new Object();
    WeakReference<Object> newReference = new WeakReference<>(newLock);
    WeakReference<Object> oldReference = MONITORS.computeIfAbsent(id, _ -> new WeakReference<>(newLock));
    Object oldLock = oldReference.get();
    while (oldLock == null) {
        if (MONITORS.replace(id, oldReference, newReference)) {
            return newLock;
        } else {
            oldReference = MONITORS.get(id);
        }
    }
    return oldLock;

}

private void maintain() {
    for (Iterator<WeakReference<Object>> iterator = MONITORS.values().iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
        WeakReference<Object> reference = iterator.next();
        if (reference.get() == null) {
            iterator.remove();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When reading this question. the Implementation of semaphore comes to mind. Essentially it allows you to create a fixed amount of access permits to a resource or logic set within java code. Inside your object with critical resources to gain access to the critical code, you can implement some logic which will let the accessing thread aquire() a permit or be rejected. the great thing about this is that the thread utilizing the critical resource can return the permit to a pool after it is finished.

here is the Java doc link for info on it: 
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html